# Redirecting outside of a controller

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, laravel-4.2

**view.blade.php (JAVASCRIPT)**

```
window.open(url);
```

**Controller**

```
echo '<script>window.close();';

Redirect::to('mainpage')->with('msgBox','Succuss');
```

`Redirect` function does not work. After I open and close the plugin, I would like to redirect to the mainpage.

Comment: In the last line you have a typo. It is 'Success' not 'Succuss'.